# Problem with ScatterView - Components behind disabled

Tags: wpf, components, button, scatterview

I'm working currently on a simple project which consist of a ScatterView with a lot of items and then a Navigation (Implemented as many buttons).

The problem is that i will like to have the ScatterView on top of everything, so that users can interact on the whole window as they want.

I tried different things:

- If I put the navigation on top of the ScatterView then as soon as someone draggs something into the navigation, then after releasing the item, it will fall down behind the navigation, and you are not able to pick it anymore.
- If I put the navigation behind the ScatterView, then I cannot click the navigation since the scatterView consumes all events.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you working in WPF, Microsoft Surface? Can you please describe the technologies you are trying to use?

Answer (score 1):

set Background="{x:Null}" on the scatterview and then put it on top of your other stuff

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are using WPF and Surface.
If that's true,
maybe you can put the Navigation-Stuff inside the ScatterView, together with the other items that you want to move/scale/rotate,  and if you do not want the navigation to be moved you can you disable "CanMove", "CanRotate" and "CanScale" and give the Navigation a fixed position in your scatterview with "Center" and "Orientation" .
So the items and the navigation will be on the same layer.